# localization with custom views

Tags: ios, localization, storyboard

Localization stop working when set the class attribute of a view on the storyboard to custom UIView subclass. The localized strings in storyboard.strings are not read.  I have tested UILabel, UITextField and UIButton. UIButton works fine, but not UILabel and UITextField. Can anybody tell me why and what's the best practice for localization when use custom UIView ?

Comment: So you have a `UIView` and you're setting the class to `UILabel`? Why?

Comment: @Wain No, I have a UILable and set the class to a subclass of UILabel.

Comment: Give details of what code is in your custom subclasses.

Comment: Same problem as referred to here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16928670/ios-storyboard-localizable-strings-do-not-work-on-uilabel-subclasses