# When subclassing textfield, locale is not picking up from storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, locale

I have a `UITextField` which shows `UIPickerView`. To disable the edit menu, I subclassed `UITextField` and assigned it in the storyboard. But now the textfield is not changing the value according to change in locale. It always shows the value in English even if I switch to Arabic.

```
class PickerTextField: UITextField {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func caretRect(for position: UITextPosition) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect.zero
    }

    func selectionRects(for range: UITextRange) -> [Any] {
        return []
    }

    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        UIMenuController.shared.isMenuVisible = false
        self.resignFirstResponder()
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue: [iOS Storyboard localizable strings do not work on UILabel subclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16928670/ios-storyboard-localizable-strings-do-not-work-on-uilabel-subclasses). The bug affects both `UILabel` and `UITextField`.

Simplest solution would be to localize the text field in code.