# Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm getting a strange error: `'Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle NSBundle'` when trying to run my app on a real iOS device.

I have the file in my directory, and it works fine in the simulator. However, in the `Copy Bundle Resources` section, the file `Main.storyboard` is red.

I've tried removing it and adding it again, restarting Xcode, cleaning build, etc. with no avail. This is the warning I get in Xcode:

```
/Users/ajay/Documents/avx/avx/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard: Internationalization of /Users/ajay/Documents/avx/avx/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard is not available when compiling for targets before iOS 6.0
```

Comment: I described how to solve the problem inside this post:

   http://stackoverflow.com/a/21098195/1141395

Comment: This issue mainly happens because of corrupt app installation. The solution is to clean and build the project. Also remove the existing app from device/simulator and run again.

Comment: **Xcode 11** users, scroll down to the https://stackoverflow.com/a/58452686 , possibly it's exactly your case.

Answer (score 130):

open the info.plist of your project and remove the selected row displayed in screenshot[image]

If you get a black screen ensure your new initial storyboard is selected as your main interface
[image]

## For 2021...

You must also edit `UIApplicationSceneManifest`. See the more recent answers below.

Comment: Thanks, but this just made my app launch with a black screen. No crashes though.

Comment: Make sure to have these two lines in your - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions...: (1) self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]; (2)
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

Comment: @ Carpetfizz
Add '[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];' to your AppDelegate.

Comment: "app launch with a black screen", nobody has any idea for this?

Comment: @Umitk set the background to white (view.backgroundColor = .white) or any other color you like

Comment: If you get black screen - note that with Xcode 11 / iOS 13 - Your manual `window`, `MyViewController()` and `makeKeyAndVisible()` logic has to go in `SceneDelegate`'s `func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo ...` method. See Parth Tamane's answer for details.

Answer (score 113):

For anyone facing this issue on Xcode 11, here's how you fix it if you face this issue when *doing storyboard less project setup*

(Adding some parts that *ricardopereira* missed)

1) First, delete the Main.storyboard file

2) Next, go to *PROJECT_NAME* -> *GENERAL*

In main interface drop-down, delete the text **Main**

[image: removing reference to main from general settings]

3) Now go to info.plist and delete **Storyboard Name**

[image: removing reference to the storyboard from info.plist]

4) Finally, modify *scene(_:willConnectTo:options)* code in the file **SceneDelegate.swift** (Yes! It's not in App Delegate anymore.)

```
var window: UIWindow?


    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        window = UIWindow(frame: windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)
        window?.windowScene = windowScene
        window?.rootViewController = ViewController()
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

You can also refer to this video instead: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Htn4h51BQsk

Comment: _**Your answer is almost correct just there is a little change in scene function:**_

`guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        let viewController = ViewController()
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            self.window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            self.window?.rootViewController = viewController
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }`

Comment: To add some emphasis, the info.plist entry is not just the usual main storyboard entry but ALSO the one in the application scene manifest which is new for iOS 13.  I had to read through twice before I realized.

Comment: This is the right way of doing things now! ^^ Apple kept changing things.

Comment: If you are a Xamarin dev, I found this to be very helpful: https://talkwithangel.com/creating-xamarin-ios-views-imperatively-without-storyboards-with-ios-13-breaking-changes/

Comment: For me in Build settings there was no "Main Interface" field. Instead I had to go under "Build Settings" > "Info.plis Values" > delete "UIKit Main Storyboard File Base Name" entry

Answer (score 63):

You may check the target membership of the storyboard. May be there is where the problem is:

It should be looking like this:

[image: Target Membership]

Comment: I had the same issue and at first I thought I wasn't copying the right resources to the target, but fixing target membership fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks, worked!  I did Clean, Rename File, Update Plist with no joy.  It's always the most obvious that gets you.

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same issue but the target membership window is not showing, Xcode 7. Please help

Comment: For some reason, my target wasn't selected.. Thanks for this answer.. Solved!!

Answer (score 62):

An update for applications created for iOS 13.0 and above. (Xcode 11)

If you get the error "Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle even after changing the "Main storyboard File base name" in the info.plist and "Main Interface" under Deployment in Target.

Then you have to change another entry in the info.plist file.

1. Open the info.plist file.
2. Expand "Application Scene Manifest".
3. Expand "Scene Configuration".
4. Expand the item 0 under "Application Sessions Role" and then change the storyboard name there.

[image]

And your application will start working.

Comment: This is absolutely the right answer. It's apparently no longer enough to set the main storyboard from the General > Main Interface dropdown.

Comment: Thanks for this. Deleting the "Application Scene Manifest" key (along with all of its sub-keys) resolved the problem for me.

Comment: Thanks this is worked for me. if view is setup programmatically, you can just set the value to "LaunchScreen".

Answer (score 27):

In a project that uses **`UIScene`** in iOS 13 and Xcode 11, you need to remove the `UISceneStoryboardFile` key from the `.plist`.

#### Xcode 11:

[image: xcode11-uiscene]

#### Changing directly from the file:

[image: uiscene-plist]

Answer (score 15):

I deleted the app from my phone, did Product-->Clean, and loaded it again. That's all it took for me.

Comment: for every execution if deletes then only its executing me ...please help me in xcode 10.1

Answer (score 13):

I got this error, however, it was my intention to remove storyboards completely.

Removing the 'Main Storyboard file base name' key from my plist cured the error.

Answer (score 13):

If your xcode version is 14.0.1 or higher,
[image]

Delete the name in 'UIKit Main Storyboard File Base Name' shown in the picture.

And
[image]
Target -> Info -> Main storyboard file base name
value should be deleted.

Answer (score 10):

#Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle

**Reason I could think of:**

As far as my iOS knowledge concluded me, this was just happened because the XCode was unable to find the reference to the Main.storyboard file within my project directory to copy it into the App.

**Resolution:**

1. Selected the Main.storyboard file and tried to delete, and from the dialog that pops up as follows:
   [image]
2. Clicked "Remove Reference" button.
3. Then, from the actual place where I could find the Main.storyboard file within the project directory, dragged, and dropped to the XCode, and again from the dialog that pops up as follows:
   [image]
4. I choosed, "Create folder references" (because that's one thing I intended to do because I've changed my project's file and folder structure). But most of the times choosing "Create groups" also might work. And clicked on "Finish" button. My Storyboard files were already within as shown in the screenshot already within a `Base.lproj` directory as follows: 
   [image]

**Note:** One important thing to remind here at this step is, don't forget to tick it ON the checkbox "Add to targets" to your app.

5. Clean the Product, re-build, and if it is successful, most of the time try running it will be successful.

I tried this on XCode 7.3.1 and on iOS Sim 9.3 and iPhone 6S!

Comment: Please help this am also facing this issue after installing the os10.14.1 and xc0de 10.1..am trying to resolve from 3 days but still ..my project works good in xcode9.1..

Comment: @ArunaM Did you try the above steps which I have given in the answer? What was the status after doing this?

Comment: This was the solution when I removed a ViewController from the project which caused same error!

Answer (score 9):

New in Xcode 14, setting the Main Interface has moved to Targets -> Build Settings -> Info.plist values -> `UIKit Main Storyboard File Base Name`. You'll need to remove the reference from here instead of under the Deployment Info like before.

Comment: This worked for Apple's LiDARDepth sample project.

Comment: Some responses said that if there is no "Main Scene" in General Tab under Deployment Info, it means that the app is configured for No Storyboard but this works

Answer (score 8):

Follow the steps:

1) First Click your story board

2) Then Click File Inspector

3) Then select "Target Membership"

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 8):

### Swift 5.1 & xCode 11.2

In my case, I forgot to change **`Storyboard Name`** in **`Info.plist`**

[image]

**`Info.plist`** source code

```
    <dict>
        <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
        <false/>
        <key>UISceneConfigurations</key>
        <dict>
            <key>UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>UISceneConfigurationName</key>
                    <string>Default Configuration</string>
                    <key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
                    <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).SceneDelegate</string>
                    <key>UISceneStoryboardFile</key>
                    <string>AccountViewController</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Answer (score 7):

The simulator is not case sensitive, but the device is. If your storyboard is called MainStoryboard, not MainStoryBoard, this will cause your problem.
and aslo
* dont use the extensions write only the story board name

main.storyboard -> only **main** is the storyboard name

Answer (score 6):

Also, try removing the Storyboard name

[image]

Answer (score 4):

1. Open you storyboard file
2. Then Click File Inspector
3. Then select "Target Membership" and check your project
4. Do the same for ViewController file   **!!!important part if you use ViewController.swift or ViewController.m with your storyboard!!!**

Answer (score 4):

This error come, while you recover your main.storyboard file from trash after delete your file. I also faced same issue yesterday.

You have to set the location path of the main.storyboard as Relative to Group in file inspector of main.storyboard. After that in the same attribute, you have to insure the check mark on your app target (as you can see in attached picture).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In XCode 14.1, If you do not want to use Main.StoryBoard and deleted it, then see image and Remove "Main" at step-4.

If you have added a Main Story Board Then write "Main" at Step-4.
[image: This Image is showing you how you can resolve this Main problem]

Comment: Just ran into this issue running Xcode 14.3. This solved my problem. I did do a cmd+shift+f and searched for "main", which also lead me to the exact line label with 4 in the screenshot of the post

Answer (score 2):

Two different solutions that worked for me after upgrading to Xcode 10.1:

- In **File->Workspace (or Project) Settings**. Switch to **Legacy Build System**.
- In your targets **Build Phases**, remove the **Base.lproj** folder from **Copy Bundle Resources** (if listed) and make sure each of your storyboards are listed and copied separately instead.

After applying either of the fixes above make sure you **Clean Build Folder** from the Product menu once, otherwise the fixes might not work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting row in plist caused black screen in my app too. And I fixed it by enabling **target membership** of the storyboard

Answer (score 1):

As Kalpit Gajera has said, "open the info.plist of your project and remove the selected row displayed in screenshot".  You simply remove 'Main storyboard file base name' from the Info.plist.  After you remove it, clean and run, the program will no longer fail but will show a black screen.  Open Info.plist again and manually add the row back in.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

If still you have black screen, then try adding below code in your scene delegate

willConnectTo

```
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    window = UIWindow(frame: windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)
    window?.windowScene = windowScene
    let navController = UINavigationController()
    let mainstoryboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Your storyboard name", bundle: nil)
    let initialController = mainstoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "your initial controller Identifier") as! initialController
    navController.addChild(initialController)
    window?.rootViewController = navController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Answer (score 1):

For my project named `ZHE Admin` I changed name of the main storyboard to `home`. Other than changing it in `info.plist` file, I had to change it in the build settings like shown in the screenshot here.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was about **localization**.

I had both Main and LaunchScreen storyboards in Italian only, fact that made Xcode store the compiled storyboards under a `it.lproj` folder, inside the application root folder.

The problem was that in my `Info.plist` the key `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` (or `Default localization` if edited from Xcode IDE) was set to **"en"**, making the app to look for an english storyboard that doesn't exists. Setting the key back to **"it"** solved the issue for me.

I just tested it on an iPhone 15 simulator (iOS 17.0) with Xcode Version 15.0 (15A240d) on an Ionic/Capacitor project with these specs:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.18.1 
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 6.2.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 14.1.0
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 14.1.0
   @angular/cli                  : 14.1.0
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 6.1.0

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI      : 4.0.1
   @capacitor/android : 3.6.0
   @capacitor/core    : 3.6.0
   @capacitor/ios     : 3.6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

choose main.storyboard,  change the view as iOS 6.1 and earlier, then xcode will tell u what u need to do.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

When I added a Seque Connection between two Views and in the Projekt Configuration the Deployment Target is less then 8.0 I get this error.

Ok, easy understanding when you develop for IOS 6.0 (for example) you can't use Seque, because the Seque needs IOS 8.0 or later.

So, I set the Deployment Target to 8.0 and the error is gone!
Other while, I cancel all the Segue Connections and handle it with IBAction, old school.

Answer (score 0):

I was moving Main.Storyboard file to "blue" sub folder which was causing issues, I had to add sub folders following these instructions 
[Xcode 6.3 New File Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29664278/xcode-6-3-new-file-issue)

then moving Main.Storyboard file to yellow sub folder did work for me

Answer (score 0):

My issue was resolved by removing the `.xml` suffix from the `Main.storyboard.xml file`.

Apparently, the suffix changed from the version from which I imported the project.

Therefore, renaming the file (removing the `.xml` suffix) and restarting, then `Project-> clean....` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your storyboard is added in project (which you'll determine from Project File Inspector section of xcode utility area)[image: Check box is marked in target membership area]

You just have to remove `Main.Storyboard` from "Copy bundle resource" (in `Build Phase`) and add it again in "Copy bundle resource". This was worked for me.[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**
If some ViewControllers are missing "Could not find a storyboard named 'ReceiverViewController' in bundle" you can add the name of ViewController in storyBoard id  and use the code below for navigation

```
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ReceiverViewController") as! ReceiverViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error occurred after resolving conflict in `project.pbxproj` file . So i went to my stable branch and i copy pasted the content of this file and it worked fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

What I did was move the main.storyboard off on to my desktop from Finder. Did a clean and build and quit Xcode. restarted Xcode now it has a red main.storyboard. I run it virtually does the same thing. Then I right click on the project folder and choose the option add files to... Browse to where it is and open it. Then when it is there to the right should be the identities inspector. Click on the small folder under location. Browse to that folder again and select choose. Then I ran and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Select the view controller you want to first show up in the list on the left side of the storyboard, then in the attribute inspector make sure its title is "Main" and the checkbox for "Is Initial View Controller" is selected.

Answer (score -3):

In my case this was due to a Pod library that was outdated

Deleting the /Pods folder and doing `pod install` fixed it for me