# Xcode folder structure issue

Tags: ios, xcode

In my projects I tend to store all my source code files in the project divided into physical subfolders inside the project. What I used to do was assuming a project structure as follows:

```
Xcode Project
MainApp
--->APIClient
------->APIClient.h
------->APIClient.m
--->Categories
------->NSSTring+Utils.h
------->NSSTring+Utils.m
```

So in the project if you hit "Show in Finder" you would see the physical (APIClient and Categories) folders as opposed the "groups" that aren't really any sort of sub directory in terms of physical folders.

What I would then do is when I wanted to link the physical sub folders I would right click the main source folder and click "Add Files to Project" and this would link up the sub folders just fine. The folder colors would be yellow too and I could easily add source files that would get added to both the logical grouping and the physical source folder directory at the same time.

Now I think I updated Xcode recently (Not 100% sure on this) but using Xcode 6.3 currently.

When I try to link physical sub folders by hitting "Add Files to project" I get this problem:

[image]

Where TestFolder used to be yellow now it is blue. And when I right click TestFolder and hit add new file, I can no longer add source files to this folder.

I would like to know, how can I reset this so that when I link the sub folders I can get the yellow folder and add files to both the logical grouping and physical subdirectory?

Thanks!

Comment: When adding files to project, make sure "Create groups" is selected, not "Create folder references"

Comment: Thanks that was what it was. I'm not sure why it got reset to folder references. Maybe with the update. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks man, I was also struggling with the same issue.

Comment: Rog, if you want to make that an answer I'll accept it to give you points.

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29664278/xcode-6-3-new-file-issue?rq=1