# Error with IOS MapKit in Xcode: Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle NSBundle

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapkit

I'm trying to use xcode to make an ios app that zooms in on a location using mapkit. I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/548-mapkit-tutorial-getting-started) and at the end of the 'Getting Started' section I get the error `Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle NSBundle`

I've been trying to use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19240054/could-not-find-a-storyboard-named-main-in-bundle), but when i remove `Main storyboard file base name` from `info.plist`,

[image]

the screen of the app is just black, when I head to `deployment info-> Main interface` and set it to main,

[image]

it just puts the `Main storyboard file base name` line back into `info.plist`

This is my ViewController.swift file, which is the only one i've edited

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var MapView: MKMapView!

    let regionRadius: CLLocationDistance = 1000
    func centerMapOnLocation(location: CLLocation) {
        let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location.coordinate, latitudinalMeters: regionRadius, longitudinalMeters: regionRadius)
        MapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        let initialLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 21.282778, longitude: -157.829444)
        centerMapOnLocation(location: initialLocation)
  }


}
```

Comment: can you github your current demo

Comment: Are you using storyboard for building UI? What is the name of your storyboard?

Comment: Do actually have a storyboard named Main in the project?

Comment: Do you add main.storyboard and copy it with resources?

Comment: I thought I had the newest version of XCode but it turns out I was using XCode 8, the problem didn't exist any more when I opened up XCode 10